# How do you handle a mouse cursor in the FPS game?

Tags: c++, keyboard, directx, mouse

I'm making an FPS game. In the FPS game, the mouse cursor is in the middle of the screen. So I put the mouse cursor in the center with the next code. But how can I solve this problem when the camera stutters very much every time I move the mouse?

```cpp
SetCursorPos(CRenderMgr::GetInst()->GetResolution().fWidth / 2, CRenderMgr::GetInst()->GetResolution().fHeight / 2);
```

`CRenderMgr::GetInst()->GetResolution()` is Screen Width and height

Comment: I expect there is some bug in your code related to your handling of mouse position.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ disable mouse cursor".  You should add the operating system or the GUI Framework to the search text.

Comment: Hi, you can manipulate ANSII escape sequences, maybe, which let you move the cursor around the screen and disable it whenever you want. You can look here: https://github.com/JustWhit3/osmanip in particular, the function `SET_CURSOR_VIEW`

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is referred to as 'relative mode' mouse movement.

For classic Win32, this is typically done using "raw input". See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/taking-advantage-of-high-dpi-mouse-movement).

> If you want "raw input" to also to work in a Remote Desktop, see [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/main/Src/Mouse.cpp#L737). In Remote Desktop, you don't get `MOUSE_MOVE_RELATIVE` data, and in normal desktop scenarios you never get `MOUSE_MOVE_ABSOLUTE` data.

For UWP, this is implemented as mentioned in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/relative-mouse-movement).

> You can see the `Mouse` class in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Mouse).